# Mongoose findByIdAndRemove() throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

On my Backend I want to delete a document, marked by its ID in my MongoDB Databse. Therefore i am using the below code. But instead of deleting it it throws an error that it can't set the property '_id' of undefined

Code:

```
Seller.findByIdAndRemove("594801105cb8571868f9cd55",function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '_id' of undefined
    at resetId (Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:204:16)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._applySetters (Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:637:22)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:661:16)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1021:17)
    at ObjectId.castForQuery (Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:189:15)
    at cast (Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:232:32)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2933:12)
    at castQuery (Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2835:18)
    at model.Query.Query._findAndModify (Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1980:17)
    at model.Query.Query.findOneAndRemove (Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\mquery\lib\mquery.js:2585:15)
    at model.Query.Query._findOneAndRemove (Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1944:31)
    at Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\kareem\index.js:257:8
    at Z:\Documents\Programming\Projext XY\repo\node_modules\kareem\index.js:23:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. 

See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In this context it means *"create a minimal program"* that only defines the schema you use, inserts some data and then tries to execute your method. Once you have done that, if the problem is reproducible then you can post the code of the "minimal program" here, and someone will look at it. More often than not, the process of creating the "minimal program" actually highlights your mistake for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of searching I found the solution. The problem was that in the version of mongoose that I was using, this bug appears whenever the option:

```
runSettersOnQuery: true
```

was set on the Schema. With the latest version up on Github this problem is solved